# ExtJS — How to load store data manually after ajax call?

Tags: extjs, store, extjs6

I rewrite my working [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28nq) from `ajax` proxy type to `memory`. I'm trying to load `memory` store data manually:

```
// app/model/Employees.js file
Ext.define('Fiddle.model.Employees', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    entityName: 'Employees',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'profile_pic'
        },
        {
            type: 'int',
            name: 'age'
        },
        {
            type: 'string',
            name: 'last',
            mapping: 'name.last'
        },
        {
            type: 'string',
            name: 'first',
            mapping: 'name.first'

        },
        {
            type: 'string',
            name: 'email'
        }
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items',
            totalProperty: 'total',
            successProperty: ''
        }
    }
});

// app/store/Employees.js file
Ext.define('Fiddle.store.Employees', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    pageSize: 30, // items per page
    alias: 'store.employees',
    model: 'Fiddle.model.Employees',
});

//app.js fule - launch() function
var store = Ext.create('Fiddle.store.Employees');
console.log(store);


Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'mates.json',
    success: function(resp) {
        var result = resp.responseText;
        console.log(result);
        // store.loadRawData(result);
        store.loadData(result);
        console.log(store);
        console.log(store.getAt(0));
    },
});
```

As result I have 3386 records in store, every symbol in my json file. And what I see in console as first record:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

And where I need to put `proxy` lines - in model or in store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it in this way:

```
//in Grid panel js file
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(grid, evt) {

        var myStore = grid.getStore();

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'mates.json',
            success: function(resp) {
                var result = Ext.decode(resp.responseText);
                myStore.getProxy().data = result;
                myStore.load();
            },
        });

    }
}
```

In store `autoLoad: true` must be disabled. This way of loading instead of `store.loadRawData(result);` shows the correct number of records in the `pagingtoolbar`.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Just have the store load the data via ajax.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I need to read data one time from json file (no write operations), so I'm using `memory` type and load data manually with Ajax.

Comment: It's just making it more difficult. Set the ajax proxy on the store and autoLoad it.

Comment: Far-fetched thought: This is an XY problem. @Sogl is searching for `queryMode: 'local'` on the combobox...

Answer (score 1):

`responseText` is a string, which contains the serialized JSON data. You have to deserialize it into an object before you can use `loadRawData` to load the object through the model converters into the store:

```
var result = Ext.decode(resp.responseText);
store.loadRawData(result);
```

`loadData` and `loadRawData` differ in that `loadData` does not call the converters on the model. `loadRawData` is equivalent to what the ajax proxy does, `loadData` is not.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I did a little differently, see my own answer. But I don't know if I chose the grid event correctly for this thing =)